# Linq context behaviour

Tags: c#, linq

I am using linq

```
var remove = WE.Item.Where(key => !response.Any(p2 => p2.ItemID == key.ItemID)).ToList();
```

and occure error. This is because i am using ToList()? How to fix it?

> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'IBD.Models.Stool'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are
>   supported in this context.

Comment: Please provide more details about the underlying LINQ provider you are using. EF (if so version)? Linq-to-SQL (if so version)? Something else (if so version)? Sample values for the variables shown in your question? It's not because of you using `ToList()`. If you have used `ToList()` with an in-memory collection of objects you would never have gotten such problems for example. It's because of the underlying LINQ provider that you are using not able to parse/support the expression you have provided in your Where clause. So please understand that LINQ is a query language over specific provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to pull the ids out of `response` first so you can pass the list into your Linq provider

```
var ids = response.Select(p => p.ItemID).ToList();
var remove = WE.Item.Where(key => !ids.Contains(key.ItemID)).ToList();
```